# Ассинхронные функции в Node.js

Tags: функции, node.js

Перешел с C#  на Node.js. Никак не могу понять, как работают функции с колбеками. Не могли бы вы просто и понятно объяснить что к чему? Как оно работает?

Comment: [Начнем, пожалуй, вот с этого.](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/async)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Странный вопрос. Не совсем понимаю, вопрос про то "что такое колбеки в node.js" или "зачем колбеки в node.js", или "как их использовать".

Есть у вас метод:

```
function processData () {
  var data = fetchData ();
  data += 1;
  return data;
}
```

Какая здесь проблема? Если `fetchData` занимает много времени, то это заблокирует выполнение всей программы. Node.js позиционируется как асинхронная платформа и не ждёт, когда завершатся операции по типу работы с I/O.

Выше приведённый метод будет на node.js выглядеть так:

```
function processData (callback) {
  fetchData(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Ошибка!");
      callback(err);
    }
    data += 1;
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

На первый взгляд это кажется ненужным, но колбеки - основа node.js. Колбек как бы говорит "когда сделаешь это, сделай потом это". Это позволяет вам иметь множество IO операций одновременно. К примеру, в веб-сервере с тысячами входящих запросов с множеством блокирующих операций это позволяет продолжать работу и не ждать выполнения этих блокирующих операций.

Типично это выглядит так:

```
function asyncOperation ( a, b, c, callback ) {
  // ... много тяжёлой работы ...
  if ( /* ошибка */ ) {
    return callback(new Error("Ошибка произошла"));
  }
  // ... ещё поработаем ...
  callback(null, d, e, f);
}

asyncOperation ( params.., function ( err, returnValues.. ) {
   // код выполнится после завершения асинхронной операции
});
```

Основная идея в такой конвенции в том, что колбек передаётся последним параметром. Он вызовется после того, как функция завершит все операции. Традиционно первый параметр - error. Если метод завершится с ошибкой, тогда вызывается колбек с первый параметром `Error`. Если метод завершится как положено, то колбек будет вызван с первым параметром `null`, а в остальных какие-то значения.